# Exception - Region with the given name is already registered. How to call a region in xaml multiple times

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism, cal

While working in WPF application. I am trying to use a region multiple times in XAML. But can not as getting a runtime exception "Region with the given name is already registered: DeviceListRegion"

I am trying to do something like.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Regions.DeviceListRegion}"
                    Grid.Column="0"/>
        <GridSplitter 
        ResizeDirection="Columns" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Width="3"
        Height="Auto"
        Background="Black"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="0"/>
        <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Regions.DeviceListRegion}"
                    Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

My requirement is I need to call the same view multiple times in different xaml. What is the correct way to do that?

EDIT:-  My specific scenario is I have MainProject where I have a UserControl registered with Region in MainProject only and is also used there.

```
<ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static UIFramework:Regions.PropertiesRegion}" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Now I have created another Project which is not refering to main project. but still I want to use the same region "Regions.PropertiesRegion".

```
 <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static UIFramework:Regions.PropertiesRegion}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Properties">
            <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static PwrGui:LocalRegions.AnotherRegion}"/>
        </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
```

This code is throwing an exception "Region with the given name is already registered.". How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you be more specific please? It's not possible to define two regions with the same name. Prism regions are named placeholders within which views can be displayed... so if you had two regions with the same name then it would not be possible to tell which region you are navigating to.

Comment: I am sorry, but you didn't tag me in your comment... I didn't see this... but still I think you are solving wrong problem. You can't have two regions with same name for the reason I said earlier.